# Returning the length of the shortest word in a string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, function

I'm trying to write a function that returns the length of the shortest word in a string. It only works some of the time and I can't seem to figure out why.

```
function findShort(s) {
  const stringArray = s.split(" ");

// Compares the length of two words, then moves to the next till complete.
// Returns the words in order of length 
  const orderedArray = stringArray.sort((a, b) => {
    return a.length > b.length;
  })
  //returns the length of the first word(0 index of array) 
  return orderedArray[0].length;

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to return a number from `sort()` not a boolean. The `sort()` function should be:

```
const orderedArray = stringArray.sort((a, b) => {
   return a.length - b.length;
})
```

```js
function findShort(s) {
  const stringArray = s.split(" ");
  const orderedArray = stringArray.sort((a, b) => {
    return a.length - b.length
  })
  return orderedArray[0].length;

}
console.log(findShort("The quick brown fox ju map"))
```

You don't need to `sort()` the whole array just use `map()` to get array of lengths and then pass it to `Math.min`

```js
const findShort = str => Math.min(...str.split(' ').map(x => x.length))
console.log(findShort("The quick brown fox ju map"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using your function it seems to me you have not addressed the edge case where the sentence starts or ends with `empty string` and not provided the sort function with a `numeric value` (vs boolean one). For example:

```js
function findShort(s) {
  const stringArray = s.split(" ");  // <-- no .trim()
  const orderedArray = stringArray.sort((a, b) => {
    return a.length - b.length;  // - instead of >
  })
  return orderedArray[0].length;
}

console.log(findShort(" try set manually "))  // 0 is wrong here
```

If we address this via [String.trim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) you get:

```js
function findShort(s) {
  const stringArray = s.trim().split(" ");
  const orderedArray = stringArray.sort((a, b) => {
    return a.length - b.length;
  })
  return orderedArray[0].length;
}

console.log(findShort(" try set manually "))  // 3 is correct now!
```

Using [Array.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) is one way to achieve this and it would more or less something like this in its `ES6 variant`:

```js
let findShort = s => s
  .trim()            // <-- making sure we remove any spaces at start and end
  .split(' ')        // <-- get the words from the sentence
  .sort((a, b) => a.length - b.length)[0]  // <-- sort & take the 1st element
  .length

console.log(findShort("in case users"))       // 2
console.log(findShort(" try set manually "))  // 3
console.log(findShort("A great story"))       // 1
```

You could also write your own function which would be more performant overall since it would not need to iterate over the array multiple times (`split`/`sort` or `split`/`map`/`Math.min` etc).

Something like this:

```js
let findShort = str => {
  let t = '', r = str, s = str.trim()
  for(let i=0; i<s.length; i++) {
    !!s[i].trim()
     ? t += str[i]
     : (r = t.length < r.length ? t : r, t='')
  }
  r = t.length < r.length ? t : r
  return r.length
}

console.log(findShort("in case users"))       // 2
console.log(findShort(" try set manually "))  // 3
console.log(findShort("A great story"))       // 1
```

Where you would loop `one time only` and keep track of the last word. You would keep checking if the new one is shorter during each `for loop iteration` by simply checking the lengths. If it is then that becomes your last word etc.